# How to pass printing range of pages in javascript using window.print()?

Tags: javascript, html

I am working on a HTML and javascript project. I want to print my document using javascript.
I am using `window.print()` to print. But how can i pass printing range also? eg: If a document contains 20 pages and i want to print pages from 5-10 only.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot set a range using `window.print()`, using `window.print()` invokes your print preferences window which is native print window, where you can set the page range manually..

Perhaps you can dynamically set a class for the content you don't want to get printed, using print specific stylesheet or media queries.

Comment: Alien: Hi I am trying to print range in window.print(). Can you give me some example on how to print range using javascript

Comment: @user575219 My answer says you cannot set a range :)

Comment: How does  it work on my machine sometimes and not the clients machine.? Do you think you could look at my question. I am buliding like a HTML Element with all pages combined. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33161283/silverlight-html-bridge-printing-window-print-blank-pages

Answer (score 1):

`window.print()` does not accept any arguments,
*but* you could make use of the: [**`window.onbeforeprint`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowEventHandlers/onbeforeprint) event for your case.

Just toggle `display: none` for the sections in your page you do not wish to be printed.

Answer (score 0):

You can't do that. All [`window.print()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/window.print) can do is open the operating system's default print dialog.

But maybe you could do something like hiding those parts of site that shouln't be printed.

Answer (score 0):

You have the option of installing an ActiveX control (perhaps if this is for an internal application) that would expose those values to you through javascript.  I've used [MeadCo ScriptX](http://scriptx.meadroid.com/home.aspx) for this in the past and it's worked out quite nicely.

Answer (score 0):

I use `print` @media rule to check if it is print or not and then hide certain elements based on that:

```css
@media print {
  .hide-print {
    display: none !important;
  }  
}
```